# Unit testing basic auth

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, basic-authentication

I have some problems to unit testing my authentication method. This is my method :

```
    public int basicAuth(String username, String password) throws IOException {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("URL").openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    String basicAuth = username + ":" + password;
    String wrap = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);
    connection.connect();
    //InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    int response = connection.getResponseCode();
    Log.v("Reponse HTTP : ", String.valueOf(response));
    responseCode_ = connection.getResponseCode();
    return responseCode_;
}
```

This is my testing code :

```
@Test
public void basicAuth() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Base64.class);
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    int responseCode = 200;
    int integer = auth.basicAuth(username, password);
    assertEquals(responseCode, integer);
}
```

I'm using Powermock because i have an error with Base64 which is not mocked. And now, when i use Powermock i have this error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.lang.String.(String.java:566)
>       at com.example.local.app_android.Authentification.basicAuth(Authentification.java:96)
>       at com.example.local.app_android.AuthentificationTest.basicAuth(AuthentificationTest.java:34)
>       /.../
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

(I have cut the middle of the error)

Do someone have an idea of where the error comes from?

EDIT N°1

```
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

Comment: You could just do some debugging to find out what's null.  But hint - mocking something means that none of its methods do anything any more...

Comment: It seems that my error comes from the line "    basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));"
I'm really not an expert; does it means that i should not use a mock ?
because when i don't, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are missing the expect so:

```
Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

Return null, which explain why the constructor of String throw a NPE.

You should also look at the documentation especially since you should be using replay and verify when you use mock and you are not (which means you are not testing that the mocks are called): https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is: you shouldn't write code that is so hard that you need PowerMock in order to test it.

Meaning: by using **static**, you created hard-to-test code. Instead: learn how to write code that is easy to test (start [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for example).

Then refactor your code, to avoid the static call; for example by wrapping that encode() methods into a tiny wrapper interface (you can still implement the interface using those static methods by the way).

As said; the real answer is to avoid the need to mock static calls; and thus avoid the need for PowerMock. Beyond that; mocking static calls with PowerMock works fine; you simply have to follow the exact [recipe](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic) as outlined by the PowerMock folks.

And to be clear about that: you still have to look into the exact details of what your solution; as user Charlesworth already predicts the next NPE problem in your code (and he is typically spot on).

Comment: Agree with this.  But note that even if the OP followed this advice, their test code would still throw an NPE.

Comment: I agree with you too, my code isn't really "clean", this is my first real project. But now i'm running out of time, and i have to proceed to my tests. I'll try to see if i can avoid that. This is the first time i meet a "mock"

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth gave you credit for your comment ;-)

Comment: @S.LeGalloudec In that case: carefully study that link I included; and see where things deviated. If you still cant figure it out, please provide a **real** [mcve] containing the "full" code for us to look at.

Comment: Some time you have no choice but to test the code has it his, that why PowerMock exists.

Comment: Far too often people accept such statements as "givens"; but nobody every really challenged them. But yes, I hear you; and I think I addressed this part in the last two paragraphs of my answer.

Comment: Ok so i edited my program and now my NPE is gone. My only problem is now the use of Mockito : i don't find "replay" and "verify" methods. Is it because i use a recent version ? I edited my post to put my dependencies

Comment: Mockito does not have a replay mode. You have verify though. Mockito is really different to easy mock/power mock, so should study the Mockito documentation.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I'm now using only powermock. But still no replay and verify

Comment: Too long since I used that stuff. When you have PowerMock on its own, doesn't that come with EasyMock as companion? So replay/verify would be imports from EasyMock. Or maybe: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/replayallandverifyall

Comment: But for the record: it is fine that you accepted the other answer. But you keep coming back with questions ... to me?

Comment: I accepted it because it solved the issue about the NPE. Now i'm asking questions about powermock because you look experimented. But sorry if you haven't enough time, i'll try to do it myself